# How to get cluster nodeId in vertx?

Tags: vert.x

I want to get the nodeId of the current node in cluster.

I didn't configuring the cluster programmatically when I start vertx, i just provide a file called cluster.xml on my classpath. In this case, I have no ClusterManager object.

I tried to find the right API in the Vertx object, but I couldn't find it.

So, how can i get the nodeId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster manager instance is not accessible from the Vert.x public API. But you can cast the Vert.x object to `VertxInternal`:

```
VertxInternal vertxInternal = (VertxInternal) vertx;
ClusterManager clusterManager = vertxInternal.getClusterManager();
String nodeId = clusterManager.getNodeID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Config hazelcastConfig = ConfigUtil.loadConfig(); // load config from cluster xml

ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(hazelcastConfig);
mdr.nodeId
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this way. But, is there a way to get nodeId in a Verticle?